How to use AWS Systems Manager to keep the EC2 instances up to date over AWS Organizations and multiple accounts?
I am looking to configure AWS Systems Manager (SSM) in a way that allows me to manage and update EC2 instances across multiple AWS accounts within an AWS Organizations setup.
My goal is to have all EC2 instances from my member accounts visible in the Fleet Manager of my Maintenance Account. I want to be able to patch these instances using Runbooks.
Does anyone have best practices or guidance on how to achieve this? Specifically, I am interested in the necessary IAM roles and policies, cross-account access configurations, and any other tips to streamline this process. Any advice or examples would be greatly appreciated!

use AWS Resource Access Manager (RAM) service

Leverage AWS Systems Manager (SSM) to centrally manage and update EC2 instances across your AWS Organization's member accounts. Create Resource Groups in SSM that target EC2 instances based on tags or IDs. These groups can span multiple accounts. Develop SSM documents specifying patching procedures and create SSM Automations that use these documents. Schedule automation to target your Resource Groups, triggering updates across your organization. This centralized approach ensures consistent patching with reduced complexity and improved scalability.
